# ZF2 creating project errors

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to create project using ZF2.beta. (zf create project sometest)

and i'm getting same issue as i found here http://pastebin.com/kwsXV8T8

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Zend\Code\Reflection\FileReflection::$contents in
>   /usr/local/include/ZF2/library/Zend/Code/Reflection/FileReflection.php
>   on line 272

project created but some files are empty. (bootstrap.php for example)

Are those notices OK or not? Should bootstrap be empty?

Comment: I think not. ZF are a beta only, so, wait the release candidate to get all working out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ZF2 App Skeleton https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication this was how I started using ZF2.

Their whole Github Account is pretty interesting https://github.com/zendframework

Answer (score 0):

That's because in `FileReflection.php`, line 90, the `contents` property is commented, but the `getContents` method (line 272) isn't.
It's not ready yet, so take Gabriel Santos' advice.